# What to do if your submit is outside of redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

What to do if your submit is outside of form?

Example:

```
<Root>
  <Header>
    <Button label={'SAVE'} onClick={this.clickHandler}/>  // <-- My handler for save form data
    <Button label={'DELETE'} />
  </Header>

  <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} fields={fieldsList} /> // <-- My form
<Root />
```

Should I be using getValues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From v4.2.0 you can add a ref prop to your form component and call submit() on that ref. See example at http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/examples/submit-from-parent

```
clickHandler() {
  this.refs.myForm.submit()
}

<Root>
  <Header>
    <Button label={'SAVE'} onClick={this.clickHandler}/>
    <Button label={'DELETE'} />
  </Header>
  <Form ref="myForm" fields={fieldsList} />
</Root>
```

Comment: How can i get fields values through refs. I tried looking into the this.refs.myForm.props. But fields are not there inside. How can i access the data of the form.